# How to accpet object(studJsonObject ) in Apex Contoller method?

Tags: json

Code in Javascript:

```
var studJsonObject = { "f_name":"FirstName", "l_name":"LastName" };
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.StudentRemoter.insertRecord}',studJsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a wrapper class like this.

```
public class JsonWrapper {
    Public String f_name;
    Public String l_name;
}
```

---

Modify your remote method as follows

```
@RemoteAction
public static string insertRecord(String jsonStr) {
     JsonWrapper wrapper = (JsonWrapper)JSON.deserialize(jsonStr,JsonWrapper.Class);
     System.debug('firstname '+wrapper.f_name); //Access wrapper variable
     System.debug('laststname '+wrapper.l_name);
}
```

You will get ouput like this.

```
USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|firstname FirstName
USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|lastname LastName
```

have a look at [JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm%23apex_class_System_Json) methods

Comment: @G.Ganesh try this `var studJsonObject = '{"f_name":"'+FirstName+'", "l_name":"'+LastName+'" }';`

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) link for javascript remoting.

And at the controller side do something like this.

```
public Class StudentRemoter
{
    public class studObjectWrapper
    {
      public string f_name;
      public string l_name;
    } 
    @RemoteAction
    public static string(Any return type) insertRecord(String strJsonObjResult)
    {
         system.debug('strJsonObjResult='+strJsonObjResult);
         studObjectWrapper rst = (studObjectWrapper)JSON.deserialize(strJsonObjResult, studObjectWrapper.class);
         // here is ur result
         system.debug('rst ='+rst ); 
     }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: var FirstName =  document.getElementById('fn').value;
 var LastName=document.getElementById('ln').value;
 var studJsonObject ={"f_name":FirstName, "l_name":LastName };
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.StudentRemoter1.insertRecord}',studJsonObject)                                                                                 error->Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was expecting double-quote to start field name

Comment: Ganesh, your JSON String is incorrect, It should belike this {"f_name":"FirstName", "l_name":"LastName" } USe JSON parser to check if the JSON is in correct format : http://json.parser.online.fr/